# Consolibyte QuickBooks PHP Library - How Do You Debug / View Errors?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I am currently trying to import a list of customers from my QB installation using the *_quickbooks_customer_import_request()* and *_quickbooks_customer_import_response()* methods found in Consolibyte's QB PHP library in the `docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php` file.

When I run Web Connector, it is able to establish a connection and receive the request from my server.  It then errors out on the response (where QB contacts my server and tries to pass to it response data).  The error shown in Web Connector is a generic `getLastError()` message:

[image]

When I look in the **quickbooks_log** table that the Consolibyte library created in the **quickbooks** MySQL database, I see the following:

[image]

The above doesn't show the reason for the error.  How do I log the underlying errors here?  I would prefer a solution where the detailed error description can be inserted into the **quickbooks_log** table in a JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Troubleshooting` section of the docs here:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte?s[]=troubleshooting#troubleshooting

You should start by putting the Web Connector in VERBOSE mode, and looking at what's in the Web Connector log file.

Also, check your PHP error log.

There's many different places an error could be occurring (PHP, configuration, SSL/TLS, QuickBooks, etc.) so start with the Web Connector log and go from there.

Comment: I found the Web Connector log file and the error message in question is `QBWC1041: SendRequestXML failed.
Error message: Response is not well-formed XML.`.  Is the `SendRequestXML` in this case related to the XML package sent from web my server to QB?  I did a direct copy and paste for the import request method from the example I found in the `/docs` folder and updated any variables that needed to be updated.  Is there anyway I can get the actual XML request Web Connector received to appear in the log to help with debugging?

Comment: Check your PHP error log. Any errors? 9 times out of 10 it's a PHP error. Are you outputting any data with print() or echo?